# Is it a bad idea to run WxWidgets and GTK?

Tags: ruby, gtk, wxwidgets

I'm currently writing a media player in Ruby (called [Shroom](http://shroom.rubyforge.org/)) with a GTK interface, but I use WxWidget's MediaCtrl for cross-platform audio playback abstraction. I don't want to use WxRuby for the interface as well, as I need to work with GTK's TreeView.

What kind of performance problems may arise from this? Is it so bad to have two main loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two dependencies, your application will be less desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the platform you're using, it may not be an issue.  I believe wxWidgets wraps GTK on linux.  You may need to end up using wxWidgets for your code though.